# Date changes when setting value

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm facing a strange problem, I have a function to get the current date. It may not be the best, but it's ok. I then use the function to set the value of a hidden input:

```js
function gettoday() {
  var d = new Date();
  var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
  var day = d.getDate();

  var out = (day < 10 ? '0' : '') + day + '/' +
    (month < 10 ? '0' : '') + month + '/' +
    d.getFullYear();
  return out;
}

something.attr('value', String(gettoday()));
```

When I do so the date becomes `31/12/1969`. The `gettoday()` function returns the correct date. Any ideas what could be happening? I tried debugging the call but nothing happens there. The same happens in Chrome or Firefox. Thanks!

Comment: Unable to replicate, the code you've shown works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/9ou0f2y5/. Note that `attr(...)` should be `val(...)` instead and the `String()` call is redundant, but this won't affect the outcome

Comment: Does not happen on Node.js

Comment: Why the String(...) wrapper in your last statement? Isn't the output already a string?

Comment: What is `something`, because you're trying to set its value? Can it be that this is a date input field or something and the string value you're attempting to set isn't in the correct format, so it displays incorrectly?

Comment: something is an hidden input, target.find('[name*=date]').attr('value', String(gettoday()));

The string is there since without it, in my example, the value is 31/11/-0001, so wrong in a different way.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wn78cs36/2/

Answer (score 1):

You should set the value using `val` in `yyyy-mm-dd` format, try the following snippet

```js
function gettoday() {
  var d = new Date();

  var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
  var day = d.getDate();

  var out = d.getFullYear() + '-' + (month < 10 ? '0' : '') + month + '-' + (day < 10 ? '0' : '') + day;
  return out;
}

$('input').val(gettoday());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date">
```

Comment: While this is better practice the OPs code is already works, therefore there must be some other underlying problem which your answer does not address. Downvote was not from me, just FYI

Comment: Outside the small code change Shridhar has made (`$(..).val(..)` instead of `.attr('value', ...)`), the problem he addresses seems to be the issue: a date input field should be the format that Shridhar mentioned.

Comment: @StephanSchrijver true, but the OP stated they are using a hidden input, not a date input